# $imoveis is undefined, variavel indefinida no blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

A variável $imoveis no blade esta indefinida, para mim esta correto no código.

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('title', 'Web Room')

@section('content')

<h1>Imoveis web</h1>

  <div id="search-container" class="col-md-12">
     <h1>Busque um imóvel</h1>
     <form action="">
         <input type="text" id="search" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Procure um imóvel..">
     </form>
  </div>
  <div id="imoveis-container" class="col-md-12">
      <h2>Próximos Imoveis</h2>
      <p>Veja os eventos dos proximos dias</p>
      <div id="cards-container" class="row">
      @foreach($imoveis as $imovel)
        <div class="card-col-md-3">
            <img src="/img/banner.jpg" alt="{{$imovel->titulo}}">
            <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-date">10/09/2021</p>
            <h5 class="card-title">{{$imovel->titulo}}</h5>
            <p class="card-participantes">x participantes</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Saber mais</a>
        </div>
  </div>
@endforeach
</div>
@endsection
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Imovel;

class ImoveisController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        $imoveis = Imovel::all();
        dd($imoveis);

        return view('welcome', ['imoveis' => $imoveis]);

    }

    public function create(){
        
        return view('imoveis.create');
    }
}
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Imovel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "imoveis";

    protected $fillable = ['titulo','descricao','valor_aluguel','endereco'];
}
```

Comment: Você fez um `dd($imoveis)` no seu Controller, então o Blade não será executado. Se está executando ainda, não é a partir do método `index`. Se for a partir dele, seria exibido o resultado do `dd`. Qual dos dois é?

Comment: VOcê pode postar o texto do erro completo? Pode ser q esteja indefinido um dos campos imovel->titulo por exemplo

Answer (score -3):

Na função `index()` da classe `ImoveisController` tente passar as propriedades para a view com a função `compact()` desse jeito:

```
return view('welcome', compact('imoveis'));
```

O `compact()` faz uma espécie de estruturação através do label da variável e você pode usar na blade com o mesmo nome da label `$imoveis`:

exemplo:

```
$names = ['Jon Snow', 'Aerys Targaryen']; 

$compacted = compact('names');

//saída de print_r($compacted); 

Array
(
    [names] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jon Snow
            [1] => Aerys Targaryen
        )

)
//saída de print_r($compacted['names']);
Array
(
    [0] => Jon Snow
    [1] => Aerys Targaryen
)
```

Comment: Ola continua com o mesmo erro amigo.

Comment: tente realizar os seguintes comandos na raiz do projeto em um terminal: 
`php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan config:cache`, `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan view:clear`; e retorne se continua o mesmo erro eu editei ali em cima havia um pequeno erro e sintaxe, pode tentar de novo também a linha acima?

Comment: Qual a diferença de utilizar o `compact` em relação ao código atual, `view('welcome', ['imoveis' => $imoveis])`?

Comment: Woss com o `compact()` voce pode passar várias variáveis para a blade comprimindo elas em um único array, talvez não seja a solução para o erro do Ricardo já que ele tem apenas uma, mas funciona do mesmo jeito, porém é como faço a passagem de variáveis para blade de um jeito mais elegante e com o mínimo de impacto caso precise de refatoração ou adicionar outras variáveis no futuro. Pensei que havia algum erro nesse sentido, justamente de passar a variável para o front, mas a maneira que ele está fazendo isso realmente n é tão relevante

Comment: @emmanuelpires dei os comandos mas infelizmente o erro permanece.

Comment: @Woss Sei que o compact é um pouco mais lento mas nada que vá travar a aplicação. Particularmente uso muito pois estéticamente fica mais "bonito" e fácil de ler na IDE (opinião).
Na prática >> return view('welcome', ['data' => $data, 'title' => $title, 'filter' => $filter,'user' =>$user,'outroX' => $outroX, 'outroY' => $outroY,'outroX' => $outroZ ]); //Versus compact
return view('welcome', compact('data', 'title' , 'filter' ,'user' ,'outroX' , 'outroY' ,'outroX');
Esses 2 posts do SO inglês teve uma discussão razoável a respeito do uso do compact x váriaveis explícitas
Continua abaixo >

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319729/why-does-php-compact-use-strings-instead-of-actual-variables e 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35589085/compact-vs-manual-array-declaration-on-php

Comment: @MarcosXavier Sim, eu tenho ciência, mas fico grato pelos links, provavelmente ajudará várias pessoas. Eu questionei mesmo porque a resposta foi dada como se o `compact` resolvesse o problema da pergunta, enquanto ele teria exatamente o mesmo efeito que passar o *array* diretamente, como o autor da pergunta fez.